# What does "it kind of works out" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> So, it kind of works out in a really sick and fucked-up way.

I've come across with the sentence above, and I didn't understand the meaning. I know the meaning of [work out](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/work-out)(to think carefully about how you are going to do something and plan a good way of doing it OR to calculate an answer, amount, price etc) and the meaning of [kind of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind-of) (used when you are trying to explain or describe something, but you cannot be exact) but I don't understand all together.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> Other people’s God Value is another person. This is often called
>   “codependence.” These people derive all hope from their connection
>   with another individual and sacrifice themselves and their own
>   interests for that individual. They then base all their behavior,
>   decisions, and beliefs on what they think will please that other
>   person—their own little personal God. This typically leads to really
>   fucked-up relationships with—you guessed it— narcissists. After all,
>   the narcissist’s God Value is himself, and the codependent’s God Value
>   is fixing and saving the narcissist. **So, it kind of works out in a
>   really sick and fucked-up way**. (But not really.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is one meaning of "work out" given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/work_out):

> **work out**
>   PHRASAL VERB
>
> **2** Have a good or specified result.
>   *An example of false optimism: ‘Everything always works out in the end.’*

The passage means that things seem to happen well for both the people discussed, but it's not really satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

"works out" here is used in something closer to sense 5 in the linked set of definitions "gets solved". The author is saying that the situation is resolved because of the way in which the people interact, although in a distorted an unhealthy way.